# Failure to load image with AsyncImage in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

i have a code that loads an image online with the AsyncImage module in kivy. i wrote the code in python3 which runs well on the pc but doesnt work on a packaged apk. i think this is because i packaged it using python2.7 buildozer. thanks [an image showing the error in logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5f0V.png)

this is the code

```
class Gallery(Screen,GridLayout):
    scroller = ObjectProperty(None)
    grid = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__ (self,**kwargs):
        super(Gallery, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if len(self.ids.grid.children) == 0:
            for i in range(13):
                src = "http://placehold.it/480x270.png&text=slide-%d&.png" % i
                image = MyTile(source=src, allow_stretch=True)
                self.ids.grid.add_widget(image)
```

Comment: have you enabled `INTERNET` in android permissions ?

Comment: Yes please, I added that in the spec

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your APK is missing ssl support (the URL is redirecting you to an https site...)

try adding:

```
 requirements = kivy,OTHER_STUFF_YOU_NEED,openssl
```

to your buildozer spec.

#### EDIT:

as @DipanshuJuneja commented, as of **this time** the solution works with python2 but not on 3 :(

Comment: what should i do after adding openssl to the spec. thanks

Comment: Package your app and try again. you can also put a import ssl somewhere to see if it worked

Comment: I added openssl but it was still the same. When I added 'Import ssl' at the top of my app and repackaged it, it crashes when I open it.

Comment: @DipanshuJuneja -- maybe you can share your errors -- possibly in a different SO question since my answer seems to solved the OP problem

Comment: Ah yes. Your solution indeed works, turns out I was building with python3 and it doesnt have ssl support. So this works great but it would be helpful if you edit this for people having similar problem in the future, that this works as long as you're building with python 2